# Simultaneous data slows down the application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem I am encountering is that I have 5 different diagrams that load the random generated data simultaneously causing the application to run slow. The point of the application is to let the user select which diagram he wants to view once, and all the other diagrams should be **idle** (this is not the case)...

I am starting to believe that because I have included the diagrams (diagram1.js, diagram2.js etc) in index.html, that this could be why the application slows down, because everything loads at once. I am using JQuery only to show or hide the diagram depended on the clicks.

**How can I make the user only see one diagram once, and hold the rest idle (no incoming data) until they are selected?**

This is included in index.html, inside `<body>`, `<div id = "diagram4"></div>` is responsible for showing the diagram.

```
<script src="diagram1.js"></script>
<script src="diagram2.js"></script>
<script src="diagram3.js"></script>
<script src="diagram4.js"></script>
<script src="diagram5.js"></script>
```

This is diagram4.js that holds the diagram content, keep in mind that I have not included the whole code to save space in this document.

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("diagram4",
        { 
           // Code.. 
        }); 
});
```

This is JQuery event that handles the click. When the user clicks on diagram4, then diagram4 pops up.

```
    $('[data-row]').on('click', function() {
        var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
         $('.active').removeClass('active');
         $('#table' + row).addClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: Use ajax to load. You can invoke $.getScript() function to get the script at button click.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating all diagrams when the page is loaded (`$(window).on("load", ...)`) you can provide 4 divs or the like with attached onclick handlers which would render a diagram when clicked. You can put some info text or even a symbolic picture of the diagram in the div.

Comment: Could you give an example please?