# Only run method when called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

The problem I am encountering is that my application runs slow because of how I have set up the JQuery code.

I have 5 different diagrams that I want the user to see once, while the rest should be idle.

I have wrote down a JQuery code that is responsible for showing or hiding the diagram by listening to user clicks.

**Is it possible to change JQuery method "window onLoad" with something that will run the content only when it loads up by JQuery event code?**

Here is my index.html, as you can see I have included 5 diagrams here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"><!-- NEW -->     
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs-1.6.2/canvasjs.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


    <!--Import temperaturetest.js-->
    <script src="diagram1.js"></script>
    <script src="diagram2.js"></script>
    <script src="diagram3.js"></script>
    <script src="diagram4.js"></script>
    <script src="diagram5.js"></script>

    <script> 
        $(function(){
        $("#toolbar").load("TopNavigationBar.html"); // Top navigation menu
        $("#selectTable").load("ListOfTableSensors.html"); // User select which table he/she wants to see once.  
        }); 
    </script> 

</head>
<body>

      <div id="toolbar"></div>
      <div id="diagram1"  class="table"></div>
      <div id="diagram2"  class="table"></div>
      <div id="diagram3"  class="table"></div>
      <div id="diagram4"  class="table"></div>
      <div id="diagram5"  class="table"></div>             
      <div id="selectTable"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is ListOfTableSensors.html with JQuery code below. As you can see from the code above, this file is included in index.html.

```
                </div>
                <br></br>
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <!--Set this inside a div to individuelly choose-->
                    <div id='list_row1' data-row="1"><li class="list-group-item">Exhaust Temperature</li></div>
                    <div id='list_row2' data-row="2"><li class="list-group-item">Cylinder Pressure</li></div>
                    <div id='list_row3' data-row="3"><li class="list-group-item">Mass Air Flow</li></div>
                    <div id='list_row4' data-row="4"><li class="list-group-item">Flywheel</li></div>
                    <div id='list_row5' data-row="5"><li class="list-group-item">Lambda</li></div>
                    <div id='list_row6' data-row="6"><li class="list-group-item">Knock</li></div>
                    <!--<div id='list_row7' data-row="7"><li class="list-group-item">Camshaft position</li></div>-->
                    <div id='list_row8' data-row="8"><li class="list-group-item">Fluid Temperature</li></div>
                    <div id='list_row9' data-row="9"><li class="list-group-item">Fluid Pressure</li></div>
                    <div id='list_row10' data-row="10"><li class="list-group-item">Throttle Position</li></div>
                    <div id='list_row11' data-row="11"><li class="list-group-item">Manifold Absolute Pressure</li></div>
                    <div id='list_row12' data-row="12"><li class="list-group-item">Flex Fuel</li></div>
                </ul>
            </div>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $('[data-row]').on('click', function() {
        var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
         $('.active').removeClass('active');
         $('#table' + row).addClass('active');          
    });             
 });
</script>
```

Comment: I think you need to better explain/describe the event upon which you want these images to be shown.

Comment: @awj, the question is more described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059907/simultaneous-data-slows-down-the-application

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function and call it only if the JQuery event has been fired.

```
$('[data-row]').on('click', function() {
    drawCharts();
    var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#table' + row).addClass('active');
```

});

You probably want to improve the code, maybe add a state, which defines if the charts already have been drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap everything you have in the window load function in it's own function.  Call that new function from the click event function.

Answer (score 0):

You can move diagram initialization inside the data-row click method, like so:

```
$('[data-row]').on('click', function() {
var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
 $('.active').removeClass('active');
 $('#table' + row).addClass('active');


 var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("diagram4",
    { 
       // Code.. 
    }); 
});
```

Just make sure to only create chart once, so be sure to check if chart variable is null

Comment: This worked, but if I load 5 other diagrams, it slows down the performance.. Maybe I could use switch statement to alternate between the diagrams?

Comment: I assumed you will only load one diagram on [data-row] click. Maybe you can distinguish the row clicked and load proper diagram? Does `[data-row]` somehow connected to diagrams?

Comment: `[data-row]` is only connected to the list where user clicks on. Here is an snap out of 5 different diagrams; `<div id='list_row1' data-row="1"><li class="list-group-item">diagram1</li></div>`

Comment: The structure goes like this: Inside my index.html, I have included the JavaScript code for each diagram (1,2,3,4,5). Then inside the <body> element, I have wrapped each diagram ID with `<div id ="diagram1"></div>`. The JQuery code that handles the event, is checking which diagram the user wants to check.

Comment: Please include your html (simplified, if needed) to your question

Comment: I am included my html below :)

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting an answer

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$(window).on("load", function() {

    $('[data-row]').on('click', function() {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("diagram4",
        { 
        // Code.. 
        })
        .on("rendercomplete", function() {
            var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $('#table' + row).addClass('active');
            });
        }); 
    });
```

`rendercomplete` is just an example (I don't know what events there are available). You should use an Event that triggers after the render of the chart is complete.

**UPDATE:**

Or you can leave your chart definition on load, but render it on click (make sure it is not rendered on load):

```
$('[data-row]').on('click', function() {
     chart.render();
     var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
     $('.active').removeClass('active');
     $('#table' + row).addClass('active');
});
```